# Uncatchable error in API call with HttpClient

Tags: c#, android, maui

```
public class StudentService : IStudentService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        private readonly string _baseAdress;
        private readonly string _url;
        private readonly JsonSerializerSettings _jsonSerializerSettings;
        private readonly ILogger<StudentService> _logger;


        public StudentService(HttpClient httpClient, ILogger<StudentService> logger)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
            _logger = logger;
            _baseAdress = DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android ? "https://10.0.2.2:5000" : "https://localhost:7209";
            _url = $"{_baseAdress}/api";

            _jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
            };
        }

        public async Task<Student> GetStudentAsync(int id)
        {
            var completeUrl = _url + $"/Student/{id}";
            try
            {
                var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(completeUrl).ConfigureAwait(false);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    var entity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student>(json);

                    return entity;
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"{ex}");
                throw;

            }

            return null;
        }
```

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private readonly ILogger<App> _logger;
    public App(NewPage1 mainPage, ILogger<App> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionTrapper;
        TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += UnobservedTaskExceptionTrapper;
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = mainPage;
    }

    private void UnhandledExceptionTrapper(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        var ex = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Unhandled exception thrown");
    }

    private void UnobservedTaskExceptionTrapper(object sender, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        var ex = e.Exception;
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Unobserved task exception thrown");
    }
}
```

Hi everyone.

So I'm trying to call my api service from Android emulator, but once I do it, the application, after 100 seconds, throws up a timeout exception, and goes into a break mode.

The debuger never passes this line

```
var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(completeUrl).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Now. I know the solution for this problem, because once I change port 5000 to 7179 it immediately throws me an error about invalid certificate, described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/connect-to-local-web-services#bypass-the-certificate-security-check

But still, I cant just bypass it. Can someone gently explain me why I can't catch the original error?

I did unmark "Just my code" feature in VS, but it didn't help.
GPT chat wasn't helpful either

Comment: Are you blocking further up in your call stack?

Comment: I attached an API call to a button, so nothing happens afterwards, if I understood your question correctly

Comment: I mean, are you calling this from the event handler using `await`, or using `Wait`/`Result`?

Comment: I call it with an async/await pattern like this: return await _context.Students.FirstOrDefaultAsync(l => l.Id == id).ConfigureAwait(false); Also I'll add, that the api itself workes fine with swager or postman, this problem appears only when I call API from android emulator.

Comment: 100 seconds is the default `HttpClient` timeout, so it seems likely that something is blocking the emulator itself. Where "blocking" does not mean "actively reject" but rather "silently blackhole".

Comment: Could you give me a hint, what should I do next? Any topics, keywords?

Comment: Put breakpoint in GetStudentAsync. Examine each method in call stack. Find one that isn't `await CallSomeMethod(...)`? Common problem is attempting to start an await/async inside a constructor, which is not an async context. If you find a missing `await`, and can't add it without compiler error, wrap that line and all lines after it: `Task.Run(async () => { ... optional code before await here ... await CallSomeMethod(...); ... code after await returns ... };`